# Is there a complementary way to get something like mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With straightforward usage of jQuery:

If I have a stationary box (say, a colored rectangle), and I move the mouse in or out of it, jQuery gives me events if I move the mouse cursor over the boundary of the box one way or the other.

If I have a colored rectangle that is being programmatically moved, say to the right, and I place the mouse to the right of the box and wait, the box will move under the mouse cursor and move past it, but without generating any mouse events (or at least mouse events that I am aware of).

What, if any, ways are there to receive something semantically comparable to the "stationary object, moving mouse cursor" for when the object is moving and the mouse cursor is stationary?

Comment: Are you working with canvas? I haven't a lot of experience with this, but with canvas I'm sure that you can store the coordinates of your current mouse location and calculate collision based on the changing position of the box.

Comment: As a resource: there is a book out there 'Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript' that describes how this (and much more) can be achieved with canvas very well.

Comment: Very nice question! Is it possible to get a jsfiddle or snippet with it?

Comment: @KimGysen I love Canvas and have used it to great advantage, but I'm doing old-school DOM manipulation in this case

Comment: @Gavriel What I have now, somewhat buried, is at jonathanhayward.com. After a few initial fades between black and white, there are moving images against a stationary background. Mouse over one of the images, and a (jQuery UI) tooltip will appear. But, as you might have guessed from the question, if you mouse over an image and then unplug the mouse or leave it alone, the tooltip will remain as the image you've moused over moves on past the cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating global variables to store current `pageX`, `pageY` ; set global variables utilizing `mousemove` event attached to `window` ; use `step` property of `.animate()` options to calculate current position of animated element , referencing `offsetLeft` , `offsetTop`, `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` ; check for current mouse position in relation to offsets , bottom of element.

Could also compliment process by performing same check within `mousemove` event handler

```js
var x = 0,
  y = 0;
$(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY
})
$("div")
  .animate({
    left: window.innerWidth - 150
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function() {
      var l = this.offsetLeft,
        t = this.offsetTop,
        b = this.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      // if element passes over mouse, log positions to `console`
      if ((x === l || x === l + 1 || x === l - 1) && y > t && y < b)
        console.log("pageX:", x
                    , "pageY:", y
                    , "offsetLeft:", l
                    , "offsetTop:", t
                    , "BoundingClientRect().bottom:", b)
    }
  })
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: olive;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use You could take the mouse coordinates with this snippet:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

Following this, you could set an interval for it and calculate your rectangle's coordinates and trajectory based on mouse coordinates and your coordinates. This is what I could think at.

Answer (score 0):

As its the object that's moving, it is the initiator of possible collision events, as well as the mouse move. On every frame, using [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), the object should check if it is colliding with the mouse's current position.

No ready-made jQuery solutions I can recall, but it should take just a few lines of code to implement, and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a custom-named jQuery event.

**Update.** I sketched a simple demo below. Div is bouncing left to right inside a box that tracks the mouse position. Only horizontal position is checked for collision in the example. Move mouse pointer somewhere on the way of the bouncing square, and leave it motionless. The square turns red when collision is in effect, and back to grey when its out..

Caveats. There is no way in JS to get mouse position without moving the mouse - then it emits an event with coordinates. So detection won't happen until mouse is moved at least once after page is loaded.

```js
var $cont = $('#container') 
  ,$out = $('#out')
  ,$el = $('#bouncer')
  ,mouse = { x: -1, y: -1}
  ,bouncer = {x: -1, y: -1}
;

function updateMousePos(e) {
  mouse.x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.y = e.offsetY;
  collisionTest();
}
$cont.on('mousemove', updateMousePos);

// swing it right-left endlessly
function toRight() { $el.animate({left:180}, 2000, 'swing', toLeft);} 
function toLeft() { $el.animate({left:0}, 2000, 'swing', toRight);} 
toRight(); // launch animation

function collisionTest() {
  if( mouse.x > bouncer.x  &&  mouse.x < bouncer.x + 20) {
    $el.addClass('collision');
  } else {
    $el.removeClass('collision');
  }
}

// update before every frame render
function step(ts) {
  bouncer.x = parseInt($el.css('left').slice(0, -2));
  bouncer.y = parseInt($el.css('top').slice(0, -2));
  collisionTest();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#container {position:relative; width:200px; height:50px; border:1px solid #333}
#bouncer {position:absolute;top:15px;width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#CCC;}
#out { margin-top: 60px; }
.collision {background-color:red !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><div id="bouncer"></div></div>
```