# jQuery: Check if mouse is over an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is pretty much what I'm working on: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2625/

I'm animating a div with jQuery to move left, then logging to the console when I hover over the div and when I move my mouse away from it:

```
$("div").animate({left: '250px'}, 6000);

$('div').hover(function() {
    console.log("Mouse hovered on div!");
}).mouseleave(function() {
        console.log("Mouse left div!");
})
```

Naturally, the program will run `console.log("Mouse hovered on div!");` once I put my mouse on the element.

However, if I leave my mouse idle and the animated element moves onto it, nothing in `$('div').hover(function(){})` will run. I have to move my mouse onto the element for the code to run, not let the element come to the mouse.

The same thing also happens if I hover onto the element, and then leave my mouse idle. Nothing in `$('div').mouseleave(function(){})` will run after the element leaves, until I move my mouse from its position.

Is there any way to work around this? I am working with animated divs and I need code to run even if the mouse is idle and the divs pass through it.

Comment: Animated how, with what HTML, CSS, JavaScript? These details matter, so please: include your [mcve] code so that we can reproduce your problem. I see that you've linked to a live demo, but that (again: minimal) code needs to be in your question to guard against the disappearance, or reorganisation of the linked site. Also against your own deletion of the resource (whether accidental or otherwise).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397503/is-there-a-complementary-way-to-get-something-like-mouse-events/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually take the mouse's last known position and compare it to the position of the circle. This is kind of extensive but it should get you the right results.

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3vpaoj59/

```
$("div").animate({left: '250px'}, 6000);

$(document).ready(function() {
  // record down the position of the cursor
  var cursorX;
  var cursorY;
  document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
  }
  // boolean to know if hovered or not, and to know whether to report in console.log
  var hover = false;
  // function to call by setinterval to check if mouse is within radius
  function checkMouse(){
    // find the centerpoint of the circle by taking its position then adding half its width/height to each coordinate
    var left = $("#foo").offset().left+$("#foo").width()/2;
    var top = $("#foo").offset().top+$("#foo").height()/2;
    // use pythagorean theorem to find distance between two points
    var xdist = Math.pow(Math.abs(cursorX - left),2);
    var ydist = Math.pow(Math.abs(cursorY - top),2);
    var hypotenuse = Math.round(Math.sqrt(xdist+ydist));
    // check if the distance is less than radius
    if(hypotenuse <= $("#foo").width()/2 && !hover){
      // if true and not already reported true, report then fix
      console.log("mouse hovered on div!");
      hover = true;
    } else if (hypotenuse > $("#foo").width()/2 && hover){
      // if false and not already reported false, report then fix
      console.log("mouse left div!");
      hover = false;
    }
  }
  // repeatedly call this
  setInterval(checkMouse, 100);
});
```

I changed the div's ID to "foo" for convenience. Make sure to do this as well so that the code works for your project, or modify the JS to not use "foo".

**Explanation:**

The reason why your problem was occurring was because your mouse's coords are only updated every time you move your cursor, and that's when hover states are checked by `.hover`. As such, we need to emulate the event that determines hover and call it repeatedly even when the cursor hasn't moved to make sure the hover state is updated.

Comment: I spent some time 30 mins ago writing something similar, but yours works a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: Can I talk with you about your code in the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108061/mouse-movements